# Can I use k-folding to train a model without testing set?

Tags: cross-validation

If I have few data, testing the model can be a problem as I have less data to train it, so I would like to know if it is possible to generate a model with all data I have, and give as AUC the mean of all AUC obtained with the models generated in k-folding. That is:

generate model with all data I have (no testing set available)

for i = 1:k #k-fold

take training set

take testing set

make model

test model

calculate auc of this model

endfor

finalAUC = calculate mean of all auc calculated inside the for

So, I want to obtain a model trained with all data I have and return as auc of that model finalAUC.

Can I do that? Am I doing something completely wrong?

Thank you!